# Jquery. Detect changes on input type 'date'

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

on the mobile version of my site I am using `input type=date` instead of a jquery datepicker to allow for use of the devices inbuilt datepicker as it's generally much quicker and easier to use.

I am trying to detect when 1 date field has a value inputted/changed, to then update the `min date` attribute of a second datefield, and , submit the form using ajax.

I cannot correctly detect the input or change.

```
$('#mob-gig-date-gteq').blur(function() {
    var date = $("#mob-gig-date-gteq").val();
    console.log(date)
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

(Using .change yields the same results)

If I select a date here nothing happens. On the computer if I select a date, press enter on one of the inputs (day/month/year) and THEN change the date again, the code fires.
On mobile nothing happens at all.

How can I detect the input change on a date field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the jquery `.change` method. Blur will only fire when the input loses focus.

```
$('#mob-gig-date-gteq').change(function() {
    var date = $(this).val();
    console.log(date, 'change')
});
```

[Code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNooow) tested in chrome

Comment: Ok, this is strange. As I mentioned in the question I have already tried using .change. The thing is, your example works fine, but the same thing on my site doesn't.

Comment: @Rob Have you checked the input tag has and id mob-gig-date-gteq and jQuery is added to the page?

Comment: Yes. If I press enter on any of the inputs (Day/Month/Year) everything starts to work.

Comment: Dammit. It was a stupid error on my part. Everything is working now. What a waste of 2 hours!!!

Comment: @Rob sometimes you just need to talk it though with someone even if they are just there to smile and nod. Happens to me all the time!

Comment: FYI: These events will fire with a blank value if the keyboard is used to select a date that is not valid. ie. Feb 30.